# JavaScript or jQuery "Are you sure?" dialog for <A> link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link in my HTML:

```
<a href="/DoSomethingDangerous">do something dangerous</a>
```

Visiting the DoSomethingDangerous link causes a not easily reversable action to occur.

So after the link is clicked on I would like a dialog box (eg "Are you sure?" "OK" "Cancel") to be displayed and if the user clicks Cancel the link is not visited and the browser remains at the same page.

What is the cleanest technique using either Javascript or jQuery to implement this?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that everyone using this has javascript enabled? Any user with it disabled would be able to visit the "dangerous" page with no warnings

Comment: You should be doing dangerous things via post requests only. No amount of JavaScript will prevent somebody from accidentally visiting this link if they have JavaScript disabled, and it will have no impact on a search engine spidering your site.

Comment: You might want to rearrange things..just *visiting* a link should not cause irreversible actions.  If that page does potentially bad stuff, it should maybe have a confirmation there with a form that posts back to itself to do the real action.  If you want to have a dialog that runs on the page to confirm, you could have it generate that form and submit it (or submit via ajax), and non-JS users would still see the static form dialog.

Comment: The page requires login so can't be spidered, the action is also reversible, so as long as 90%+ of people get the confirmation dialog I'm happy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript confirmation dialog on href-link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/javascript-confirmation-dialog-on-href-link)

Answer (score 86):

```
<a class="confirm" href="/DoSomethingDangerous">do something dangerous</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.confirm').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            location.href = this.href;
        }
    });
});
```

or even simpler:

```
$(function() {
    $('.confirm').click(function() {
        return window.confirm("Are you sure?");
    });
});
```

The native confirm box can't be styled.
If you want style, then you could use `jQuery.UI.dialog`

Comment: nice reusable solution!

Comment: I would like to use this but mine just blinks up and is directly set to Yes or true. This occours in Firefox as well as in Edge.

Answer (score 39):

If we know that the DOM function `window.confirm()` returns boolean `true` on "yes" and `false` on "no", our link could be simplified a little bit:

```
<a href="/DoSomething" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Link</a>
```

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected ) - You have one bracket to many at the end there, should be: `return confirm('Are you sure?');`

Answer (score 23):

I think the simplest solution will be

`<a href="/DoSomethingDangerous" onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;">Link test</a>`

Comment: This worked for me where the other option always returned true.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('a').click(function(e)
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
    {
        alert('navigate!');
    }
    else
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PDj9H/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use jQuery UI [`modal-confirmation`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) dialog - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation.