# Redirect only after confirmation

Tags: javascript, php

I want to have the user click on a link then have a javascript pop-up with a yes or no choice,but if yes redirect to different url if no, then stay on the same page.
I tried the code below but it takes me to the same page when selecting yes or no.

```
function YNconfirm() { 
 if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?'))
{
    alert("You agree") 
window.location.href = (http:///mediclaim_portal/logout2.php');
}
else
{
window.location.href = (this.document);
}};
</script>

then 
<a href="\mediclaim_portal/logout2.php" onclick="YNconfirm()">Home</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `'` before the url in the first part of your if block. And I think you only need `http://` not `http:///`. Also, returning false as stated by the answers below will help.

Answer (score 8):

```
function YNconfirm() { 
 if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?'))
 {
   alert("You agree") 
   window.location.href = 'http:///mediclaim_portal/logout2.php';
 }
}
```

then

```
<a href="/mediclaim_portal/logout2.php" onclick="YNconfirm(); return false;">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser is navigating to the link after running your click handler.

You should change your handler to simply `return false` to cancel the navigation, and not set `location` at all.

Answer (score 2):

If the code running at the onclick event doesn't return false, the href at the  happens.
i.e., try something like this:

```
function YNconfirm() { 
    if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?'))
    {
        alert("You agree");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
};
</script>
<a href="\mediclaim_portal/logout2.php" onclick="return(YNconfirm());">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do that ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function YNconfirm() { 
     if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?')){
         alert("You agree") 
         //REDIRECT
         window.location.href = (http://mediclaim_portal/logout2.php');
     }
     else{
        //DO NOTHING AND STAY IN THE SAME PAGE
        //OR SOMETHING ELSE THAT YOU WANT

        return false;
     }
};
</script>
<!-- IMPORTANT, dont link your 'a', or it will always be submited -->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="YNconfirm();">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## Try this for all url ##

<a href="https://code.jquery.com">Click Here</a>     
       <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
              //get a href url
              var url = $(this).attr('href');
              //check condition for redirection
              var answer = confirm("Leave From this page");
              if (answer){
                document.location.href = url;
              }else{
               alert("Thanks for sticking around!");
               return false;
              }
            });
          });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `window.confirm` returns a `boolean` based in our selection.

**This might help:**
[How to display a confirmation dialog when clicking an <a> link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/how-to-display-a-confirmation-dialog-when-clicking-an-a-link)

We can simply do:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=22" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Link</a>
```

Comment: The most reasonable "one line" solution without over engineering the thing with functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://mediclaim_portal/logout2.php" onclick="YNconfirm(this, event)">Home</a>
```

Then write the jquery script as follow

```
<script>
 function YNconfirm(el,ev){
    var confirm = window.confirm("Really go to another page?");
    if(confirm){
        window.location.href = $(el).attr("href");
    }else{
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not codegolf, but this is the solution I usually employ (which is slightly more readable):

```
<a onclick="if(confirm("Want to go to the new page?)){location.href = "bla.newpage.bla"}}
```

While the 'onclick return true' works, it requires internal knowledge on how onclick and href tags interact. I find my way easier on the eyes (specially if you are constantly jumping between C#, JS, SQL, etc)

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use return value of function like this

```
function YConfirm(
if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?')){
     return true;
 }
 return false;
)
```

Now simply call this function like this.

```
<a href="http://mediclaim_portal/logout2.php" onclick="return YConfirm();">Home</a>
```

Now you don't need to redirect the page with javascript.