# Delete confirmation link

Tags: php

```
echo '<td><a href="candidates.php?id=' . $row['candidate_id'] . '">Delete Candidate</a></td>';
```

How can i add a confirmation message before the data will be deleted? Like asking are you sure

Comment: javascript popup that cancels the action if the user clicks "cancel": `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');`

Comment: Or here or in the next confirmation page you should make a POST instead of a GET request. To avoid browsers and search engines auto-deleting your content by accident.

Comment: Here is the answer to your problem -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852373/redirect-only-after-confirmation

Comment: You should even be using a form with CSRF token instead of a simple link

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo '<td><a href="candidates.php?id=' . $row['candidate_id'] . '" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure...?')">Delete Candidate</a></td>';
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using a link in combination with javascript for a delete action.

Comment: @jeroen What are the downfalls to this? Personally, I've never used such combination before, as I would handle the confirmation before I make a POST request to manipulate the data.

Comment: See my comment below the question. And if javascript is disabled, there is no confirmation at all (Opera mini?).

Answer (score -1):

Use confirm function from javascript

confirm('message');

```
echo '<td><a href="candidates.php?id=' . $row['candidate_id'] . '" onclick="return confirm('message goes here')">Delete Candidate</a></td>';
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp