# Html DropDownList not generating events

Tags: html, jquery, html-select, jquery-events

In my web page I use something like this, but when a option is selected, `onchange` is not fired. I don't know where I have made a mistake. Actually my requirements is that I need to fetch location details based on the city selected, but it is not working here. Is there any other better way to do so?

```
 @Html.DropDownList("cities", ViewBag.cities as SelectList, new { onselect = "getLoca();"});    
<script type="text/javascript">
function getLoca() {
    alert("yes");
    $.post('@Url.Action("getLocations","Home")', { 'id': $("#cities").val() },
        function (data) {
            $("#loca").html(data).show();

        });
}
</script>
```

EDIT:
This is the generated HTML code

```
 <select id="cities" name="cities" onselect="getLoca()"><option value="0">--City--     </option>
<option value="1">City1</option>
<option value="2">City2</option>
<option value="3">City3</option>
<option value="4">City4</option>
<option value="5">City5</option>
</select>;                   
<select id="loca" name="loca" style="width: 170px" ></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`onchange`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.onchange.html) instead of `onselect`.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V5esF/)

[`onselect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/select) does not do what you expect - it fires when the user selects text (you know, by dragging the mouse or holding shift and using the arrow buttons), so it is not applicable to a `select` box, which has no selectable text. It works on certain `input` elements (like `text`) and `textarea`s, or you can use it on the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onselect).

`onchange` fires when the value of a form element changes - so this is what you need.

**Note:** using inline event handlers in your HTML is not a good idea most of the time. If you can, [use `addEventListener` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/javascript-confirmation-dialog-on-href-link/10462878#10462878).