# javascript confirm() cancels navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple confirm() when a user clicks a link or a button but regardless of whether they answer yes or cancel, it seems to cancel the entire navigation.

when I remove the confirm() code the navigation happens fine.

is there anyway around this? I need to confirm with the user whenever they click on any element on the page but when the confirm comes up for link or button it seems to cancel the navigation from happening.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: where you stucked? show your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript confirmation dialog on href-link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/javascript-confirmation-dialog-on-href-link)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
   if(confirm('do you wish to proceed?'))
   {
      //proceed with navigation
   }
   else
   {
      //cancel navigation
   }
</script>
```

Comment: The code you show will display `do you wish to proceed?`  when the page/script is loaded, but not at a `click` on a link. Beside that I'm pretty sure the OP has problems with the `//proceed with navigation` part.