# Laravel Confirm Dialog

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.3, confirm

I'm looking for a simple way to confirm a delete of an item (I'm using Laravel 5.3)

I have this code:

```
<a href="{{url('/deleteProduct')}}<?='/'.$product->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

So when clicking on the link, I call the route `deleteProduct/{id}`. But what I want is, that when clicking on the link, there is a prompt, saying something like sure to delete? yes/no. Only when clicking yes, this route is called then.

I tried it with a bootstrap modal and in general it worked, but I had problems with the `$product`, actually $product is an item in a foreach, so around the `<a>`-tag, there is a `@foreach($products as $product)`. That's why the modal didn't work, because it got somehow messed up with this foreach (actually $product always held the last "product", because i defined it after the foreach).

Is there a easy to achieve what I want? Alternatively I could create a modal for every product, but there could be up to thousands of those, so this would be nonsense. So whats the better way?

**Edit**: The normal javascript function `confirm()` would work, but thats a little "too basic", so I want something that fits in the design, so something with bootstrap would be nice, or anything thats not a alert dialog with two buttons. The functionality of `confirm` is the one that I want. But also, `confirm` provides the buttons in english, I may want to customize those to be used in more then one language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/javascript-confirmation-dialog-on-href-link

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Basically, I want to have something that looks a little bit more nice then something like a alert dialog with two buttons (so the basic js `confirm`). I'm gonna edit my question to include this info.

Comment: You can use any js confirm plugin (for angular, react, jQuery etc.). For example: https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/ (see section with "Quick use" with button "Goto twitter").

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved a pretty great results with [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) plugin. There is actually an example of a delete with ajax. Check it out!