# onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" Not working

Tags: django, onclick

```
<td style="width:10px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="ID{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ item.id }}">
  <span>
    <a href="{{ return }}{{ sem_id }}/{{ item.id }}/delete/"  
       onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">
      <i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:red; font-size: 25px;"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
</td>
```

Here confirm pop-up is coming with the question but when we cancel its going to the delete link and deleting the data. can u help me to do this (on cancel - go back)

Comment: Can you post the code which you are using ?

Comment: <td style="width:10px;"><input type="hidden" name="ID{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ item.id }}"><span ><a href="{{ return }}{{ sem_id }}/{{ item.id }}/delete/"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"><i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></span></td>

Comment: this is inside a table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a confirmation dialog when clicking an <a> link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/how-to-display-a-confirmation-dialog-when-clicking-an-a-link). Note that the accepted answer, first option doesn't work (it's your case), you should use a more elaborate script with `if`.

Comment: Also what's the `<input>` for? You're not using it since you're not submitting any form. You should **never** delete something on a GET request, it would be much better if your script submitted a form with POST.