# Why is the return statement underlined in onclick confirm method (VsCode)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to give a confirm to the screen before deleting the object, but the return statement is constantly being underlined.How can I fix that?

```
{% if notifications %}
{% for not in notifications %}
        <li>
            <figure><img src="{{not.object.image.url}}" alt=""></figure>
            <small>{{not.object.category.name}}</small>
            <h4>{{not.object.title}}</h4>
            <p>{{not.message}}</p>
            <!-- <p><a href="#0" class="btn_1 gray"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i> View course</a></p> -->
            <ul class="buttons">
                <li><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"  href="{% url 'deleteNotificationsAdmin' not.pk %}" class="btn_1 gray delete wishlist_close" >
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times-circle-o"></i> Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

When I hover over it with the mouse it gives an error

A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.

Comment: because it's redundant ... anything pop up when you hover over it? hmm, maybe it isn't redundant after all, clicking cancel will abort the "navigation" .... still, `onclick` is so 1999

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code so we may best assist you here - you have tagged this as JavaScript but it is perhaps

Comment: it is not redundant.Because even I press cancel button,the object deletes.

Comment: Note there is no need for the semi-colon after the confirm call in the HTML

Comment: Did you install any plugins that does linting/validation on the code? Seems like that is more at fault than the code since it is valid.

Comment: You might also tag which template engine is in play here

Answer (score 5):

So it turns out [`A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143220) error is actually a bug in Visual Studio Code and currently scheduled to be fixed in [March 2022 Milestone](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/178).

And according to [HTML 5.2: 7.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm), it is valid to use `return value` with event handlers.

> Process return value as follows:
>
> - If the event type is mouseover
> - If the event type is error and E is an ErrorEvent object
>
>   - If return value is a Web IDL boolean true value, then cancel the event.
> - If the event type is beforeunload
>
>   - NOTE: The event handler IDL attribute’s type is OnBeforeUnloadEventHandler, and the return value will therefore have
>     been coerced into either the value null or a DOMString.
>   - If the return value is null, then cancel the event.
>   - Otherwise, if the Event object E is a BeforeUnloadEvent object, and the Event object E’s returnValue attribute’s value is the empty
>     string, then set the returnValue attribute’s value to return value.
> - Otherwise If return value is a Web IDL boolean false value, then cancel the event.

As a workaround, you can disable `html.validate.scripts` option from Visual Studio Code settings.

Comment: The code is executed in a function (the code in inline listener attributes is wrapped in a function, and is then executed in `with` block).

Comment: A return statement from a `confirm()` is perfectly valid in HTML in this context and should cancel the `<a` link default action from the `href` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm  Please further clarify your answer context ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10462839/125981

Comment: Good update there!

Comment: also added a workaround