# How to display a confirm dialog when clicking an <a> link?

Tags: javascript, html

I want this link to have a JavaScript dialog that asks the user “Are you sure? Y/N”.

`<a href="?status=1">My Link</a>`

If the user clicks “Yes”, the link should load, if “No” nothing will happen.

What is the easiest way to do this?

There are several ways to do this, but I have forgotten the easiest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/how-to-display-a-confirmation-dialog-when-clicking-an-a-link)

But I introduced the simplest inline methods below

```
<a href="?status=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">My Link</a>
```

And

```
<a href="?status=1" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {return true} ; else {return false};">My Link</a>
```